# Perl Regex case insensitive

Tags: regex, perl

I'm sure I am missing something simple. The following code I am trying to match two lines of a file with regex case insensitive(//i). It still matches if the file lines are not the same with different cases.

It works fine without the pattern matching, going through the files and comparing line by line. Just trying to add case insensitivity.

```
#add file lines to array for comparison
while (my $fileLine = <FILE1>)
{
   chomp($fileLine);
   push @lines, $fileLine;
   $compare{$fileLine}++;
}
#comparison of second file to first file
while (my $fileLine2 = <FILE2>)
{

   chomp($fileLine2);
   $lineNum = 1 + $count;
   my $comp = $fileLine2;

   if ($comp =~ s/$lines[$count]//i)
   {
     print "The different line is at Line Number: $lineNum \n" unless(exists($compare{$fileLine2}));
     print "File A: $fileLine2\n" unless (exists($compare{$fileLine2}));
     print "File B: $lines[$count]\n" unless (exists($compare{$fileLine2}));
   }

}
```

Comment: Please don't edit your code to remove the errors you're asking about.

Answer (score 5):

Your code doesn't match, it replaces:

```
$comp =~ s/$lines[$count]//i
```

The `$lines[$count]` is interpreted as a regular expression, but you stored strings into the array. Not every string matches a regular expression created from it, e.g.

```
my $string = 'a+b';
$string =~ s/$string//;  # $string is unchanged
```

`a+b` as a regex means *at least one `a` followed by `b`*, which clearly doesn't apply to the string. See [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta).

You haven't shown what lines you had problems with, but you can see that it doesn't work even without case sensitivity.

To compare that $s1 and $s2 are the same regardless the case, you can use

```
lc $s1 eq lc $s2
```

See [lc](http://p3rl.org/lc), [uc](http://p3rl.org/uc), and also [fc](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html) for unicode casefolding.

You also need to store the unified string in the hash!

Comment: Amended, sorry meant worked without any regex, and i didn't have the s/. I was just trying heaps of different things. thanks for your reply